# Condition on a function to have a Fourier transform in $L^{2-\varepsilon}$

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, fourier-transform

It is known that in general the Fourier transform of $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ functions for $p>2$ are not even function. However, for regular enough functions, the regularitytransfers into decay for $\hat f$ and with sufficient decay one obtains $\hat f \in L^{2-\varepsilon}$ for some sufficiently small $\varepsilon >0$.

> Is there a condition, which does not require regularity (neither $H^s$ or $\mathcal{C}^{\alpha}$ regularity) for functions $f \in L^1 \cap L^{\infty}$ to ensure $\hat f \in L^{2-\varepsilon}$ for some small $\varepsilon >0$?

For example, take $f=1_{[0,1]} \in L^1\cap L^{\infty}$, then $\hat f (\xi)=\frac{\sin \xi}{\xi} \in L^{1+\varepsilon}$. Is there a general class of function with such properties?

Comment: Sidenote: Since $\widehat{\widehat{f}} = \check{f} := x\mapsto f(-x)$, it is equivalent to ask for a characterisation of the image of $L^{2-\epsilon}$ under FT. Since the FT maps $L^1$ into $C_0\subseteq L^\infty$ and $L^2$ into $L^2$, it maps $L^{2-\epsilon}$ into $L^q$ with $q=\frac{2-\epsilon}{1-\epsilon}$ by the [Riesz-Thorin theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz–Thorin_theorem).

Therefore $f\in L^q$ is at least a *necessary* condition for $\widehat{f}$ being in $L^{2-\epsilon}$.

Comment: @JohannesHahn this is a good observation, I will edit my question and try to phrase more carefully what I am asking. Typically, we can assume that $f \in L^1 \cap L^{\infty}$. Then we have $\hat f \in L^2 \cap L^{\infty}$ at least, which does not help in proving further integrability properties such as $f \in L^{2-\varepsilon}$.